# Shell command syntax errors

Tags: perl, email, pipe

2 examples with issues:  What is wrong with the following statement syntax (perl newbie):

```
$mailCmd = sprintf("echo $message | /usr/ucb/mail -s 'X Detected an Invalid Thing' %s", $people_list);
```

When I do `system($mailCmd)` or `` `$mailCmd` ``, it results in:

```
sh: syntax error at line 2: `|' unexpected
```

Another one:

```
$message = "Invalid STUFF setup for ID $r.  Please correct this ASAP.\n" .
            "Number of thingies  = $uno \n"   .
            "Another thingy      = $id  \n" ;
```

This produces:

```
sh: Number: not found
sh: Another: not found
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct cause of the first problem is that you are executing the following command because the contents of `$message` ends in a newline.

```
echo ...
| /usr/usb/mail ...
```

Both problems are the result of improper construction of the shell command. Fixed:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
my $echo_cmd = shell_quote('echo', $message);
my $mail_cmd = shell_quote('/usr/ucb/mail',
   '-s' => 'X Detected an Invalid Thing',
   $people_list,
);
system("$echo_cmd | $mail_cmd");
```

Or avoid `echo` and the shell entirely:

```
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );
my @cmd = ('/usr/ucb/mail',
   '-s' => 'X Detected an Invalid Thing',
   $people_list,
);
run3 \@cmd, \$message;
```

Comment: Also, thank you for pointing out additional Perl'ismsthat I can use: shell's "command" quotes, in place of the system call, and the cmd array syntax. Nicely done, and thank you :-)